# Palais-Smale and Cerami

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-analysis

I have this two definitions :

1. "$\phi$ satisfies the Palais-Smale compactness condition at the level c, or $(PS)_c$ for short, if every sequence $(u_j)\subset W$ such that
   $\phi(u_j)\rightarrow c$, $\phi'(u_j)\rightarrow0$
   called a $(PS)_c$ sequence, has a convergent subsequence"

2)"$\phi$ satisfies the Cerami condition at the level c, or $(C)_c$ for short, if every sequence suchthat
$\phi(u_j)\rightarrow c$ ,$(1+||u_j||)\phi'(u_j)\rightarrow 0$
called a $(C)_c$ sequence, has a convergent subsequence"

I don't see clearly if $1)\Rightarrow 2)$ or $2)\Rightarrow 1)$

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: If $(1+||u_j||)\phi'(u_j)\rightarrow 0$, then in particular we must have $\phi'(u_j) \to 0$, so...

Comment: There is an example on page 9 of S. Robinson. Multiple solutions for semilinear elliptic boundary value problems at reso-nance.Electronic Journal of Differential Equations, 1:1–14, 1995.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\phi'(u_j) = \frac{(1+\|u_j\|)\phi'(u_j)}{1+\|u_j\|}.$$ The denominator cannot tend to zero, and if the numerator goes to zero, then $\phi'(u_j) \to \ldots$

Comment: so $2)\Rightarrow 1)$, but if we have 1), if $\phi'(u_j)\rightarrow 0$ then $(1+||u_j||)\phi'(u_j)\rightarrow 0$ no ???

Comment: No: the sequence $\{u_j\}$ may be unbounded. This is precisely the reason why Giovanna Cerami introduced this definition.

Comment: the norme can be unbounded ?, and what is the purpose of Cerami ,what he solve with this ? thank you

Comment: I mean: in the definition of the two compactness conditions, you can't assume that $\{u_j\}$ is bounded. So the two conditions are not equivalent. There functionals that satisfy the Cerami condition but do not satisfy the standard PS condition. This may happen with asymptotically linear problems.

Comment: Could you give an example (or give me a reference) of a sequence which satisfies Cerami condition but not PS? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Siminore, if we are saying that $2)\implies 1)$, i.e. every functional that satisfies Cerami condition satifies also PS condition, how it is possible what you say? Sorry, maybe I missi something. Could you please help me?